# JPA findBy(Property) return null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, findby

I have written JPA code in Spring boot where I want to perform CRUD and other operations on an Entity, I have written RecipeRepository that extends JpaRepository

```
public interface RecipeRepository extends  JpaRepository<Recipe,Long> {

  public List<Recipe> findByName(String name);

  public Recipe findOneByName(String name);
}
```

and Entity class is;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Recipe")
public class Recipe {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
..

}
```

When I call the the **recipeRepository.findByName("test")** or **recipeRepository.findOneByName("test")**, I get **null**. When I call findAll() and then itreate over the values, I can find Recipe where name is **test**

```
String name = "test";

Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findOneByName(name);

List<Recipe> recipeList = recipeRepository.findByName(name);

Iterable<Recipe> recipies = recipeRepository.findAll();
for(Recipe recipe : recipies){
    System.out.println(recipe.getName());
    // gets value of recipe where name is test
}
```

in the logs for the findByName or findOneByName, I get the following in logs:

> select recipe0_.id as id1_0_, recipe0_.is_active as is_activ2_0_,
>   recipe0_.is_injected as is_injec3_0_, recipe0_.name as name4_0_,
>   recipe0_.rule as rule5_0_ from recipe recipe0_ where recipe0_.name=?

Comment: can u post implementation of ur method findByName()?

Comment: Some questions - In the DB, is there a space before or after test. And is your database case sensitive ? or case insensitive.

Comment: Can you pls use findByUsername instead of findByName

Comment: @Prashant thanks for pointing that out, I was passing wrong value of the param to my controller...

instead of :

**localhost:8080/recipe/test**

I was passing the value like name=test, and that is when in the debugger i could not pick it up, as it was saying value of name=test and got confused.

**localhost:8080/recipe/name=test**

Comment: @here
Do you have the setter/getter method on your Recipe class, If not try with setter and Getter method

Comment: @AdnanMian Please post this as an answer and accept it. Accepting is possible after three days I think. This way others can find the answer without hunting through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing the wrong value of the param to my controller. Instead of: **localhost:8080/recipe/test** I was passing the value like **name=test** **(localhost:8080/recipe/name=test)**.

So it was passing the value of the name as "**name=test**" to recipeRepository.findByName() method instead of **"test"**